# Error in dots[[1]] : subscript out of bounds Using dwplot() in R

Tags: r

I'm trying to create a dot and whisker plot using the results from a series of regressions. I'm using the same two independent variables to predict seven outcome variables.

Whenever I try to relabel the two predictors in a dwplot() plot, however, I get the error

```
Error in dots[[1]] : subscript out of bounds
```

If I don't try to relabel them, the plot works fine and I get no errors. Any ideas as to why this is happening?

Here's my code:

```
plotA <- dwplot(list(v1patb, v2ordeb, v3indib, v4morab, v5econb,
                     v6equab, v7freeb)) + ggtitle("") +
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(), axis.line = element_line(colour = "black")) + xlim(-1, 2) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = 0, colour = "grey60", linetype = 2) + relabel_predictors(c(ruralid="Rural", urbanid="Urban"))
plotA
```

Comment: Welcome to SO, Krissy Lunz Trujillo! Questions on SO (especially in R) do much better if they are reproducible and self-contained. By that I mean including attempted code (you have a good start here), sample representative data (perhaps via `dput(head(x))` or building data programmatically (e.g., `data.frame(...)`), possibly stochastically), perhaps actual output (with verbatim errors/warnings) versus intended output. Refs: https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269, [mcve], and https://stackoverflow.com/tags/r/info.

Comment: Thanks for the tips and the welcome. The issue is that in other data sets this similar coding works fine. I'm wondering why/under what conditions this particular error shows up.

Comment: I understand, and there's still nothing we can do lacking sample reproducible data. The times I tend to see `x[[1]]` produce "subscript out of bounds" is generally when `x` is empty, as in `list()[[1]]`. In this case, I'm not sure, since it appears that even if any/all of your `v1patb`/... objects are empty, the error is still unexpected since `list(NULL,NULL)[[1]]` works without error. Perhaps this should be a [bug report for the maintainers](https://github.com/fsolt/dotwhisker/issues)?